# How to import word documents into wiki?

Tags: wiki

Anyone knows? Because i think one of the stumbling blocks for people to embrace wiki is of the fact that they need to separately upload the images to the wiki instead of just doing simple copy/paste to the word document

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/21408/converting-word-documents-into-a-trac-wiki-format for a useful overview.

Answer (score 6):

[OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org) can save as a Mediawiki text file, ready to be pasted into the edit box online.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft has an add-on for Word 2007 and Word 2010 to save in mediawiki markup.  It can be downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=12298

Answer (score 3):

The guys at mindtouch.com told me they have a tool that imports word docs into their wiki.

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify which wiki you use, here are some links mostly related to mediawiki:

- You can use [wikEd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Cacycle/wikEd), which allows to paste formatted text
- [Help:WordToWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:WordToWiki) lists 3 alternative ways
- [Extension:Word2MediaWikiPlus](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Word2MediaWikiPlus) includes also automatical image upload.

Answer (score 1):

The folks at webworks.com have a nice desktop software solution that automatically publishes Word documents to wiki. Currently they support out-of-box: Confluence, Mediawiki, and MoinMoin.