# Import MS Office document into Atlassian Confluence via API

Tags: ms-office, wiki, confluence

Is it possible to do this? I browser through the Confluence Core API and haven't found anything remotely similar.

Google search also comes dry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import word documents into wiki?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382710/how-to-import-word-documents-into-wiki)

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Because documents I dealt with were pretty heavily templated, I was able to come up with a solution that converts 90% of them to wiki markup, but it was very ad-hoc and not something that could really be replicated elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

This must be possible, the UWC (universal wiki converter) does exactly this.

Try looking at how the UWC works
https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/UWC/Universal+Wiki+Converter

Of course I am assuming you mean to import the document as an attachment.

DC

Comment: No, I actually meant "Import document text as Confluence page text"

Comment: there is no automated way
there is a discussion here...
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Importing+an+Office+Document+into+Confluence
and you may want to upvote this here...
 https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/browse/WORDDV-3

Comment: is there any way to do this now?